# Javascript input a number in a form

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    function loop()
    {
        var input = document.getElementById('id').value;
        //var ans;
        for (var x = 1; x < input; x++)
        {
            var ans = document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML;
        }
    }
</script>
<input type="text" id="id" />
<input type="submit" onclick="loop()" value="isubmit">
<div id="hello"></div>
```

I need to input number the text field then submit it, then it will display the loop. For some reason I only get white screen. It does nothing.

Comment: are u sure ur script is working? try to put alert inside ur loop, alert something.

Comment: What should it do? you are not doing anything in the loop...

Comment: What are you trying to do here: `var ans = ...`? You store something in variable ans and don't do anything with it.

Comment: result should be display below the submit button

Comment: then.. how to call the x in the loop?... the result is supposed to be 1234 if the user input 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you wanted to do is to loop from 1 upto the inputted number minus one, then you can modify your function to be like this:

```
function loop() {
  var input = document.getElementById('id').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('hello');
  for (var x = 1; x < input; x++) {
    result.innerHTML += x + ' ';
  }
}
```

Check this fiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/arnellebalane/1ysut9L3/

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type = "text" id = "input_id" />
<input type = "submit" id = "submit_btn" value = "isubmit">

<div id = "hello">
    ...
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function LoopOnClickEvent(input_id, button_id, result_id)
{
    input = document.getElementById(input_id);
    button = document.getElementById(button_id);
    result = document.getElementById(result_id);

    button.onclick = function()
    {
        var val = parseInt(input.value);

        if(Number.isNaN(val) || val < 2)
        {
            var old = result.innerHTML;
            result.innerHTML = "Please type a real number greater than 1"; 
            setTimeout(function(){ result.innerHTML = old; }, 1500);
        }
        else
        {
            var final_val = "";
            for(var cpt = 1; cpt < val; ++cpt)
            {
                final_val += cpt;
            }
            result.innerHTML = final_val;
        }
    };
}

/* Exemple */
LoopOnClickEvent("input_id", "submit_btn", "hello");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q0f4g5gr/

I hope it will help you :)